# Catching up another train when the trains stop at regular interval : Time, Speed and Distance

Tags: solution-verification, contest-math

> A local train leaves Vijayawada for Guntur at $9 AM$. The total
> distance from Vijayawada to Guntur is $60 km$. Another express train
> leaves for Guntur from Vijayawada, $10$ minutes later. The speed of
> both the trains is $60 kmph$. However, the local train has $19$
> uniformly spaced stops while the express train has $4$ uniformly
> spaced stops. The trains stop at each stop for one minute and these
> stops do not include the destination. At what distance from Guntur
> will the second train overtake the first train? (Assume these two
> trains run on parallel tracks and no other trains run during this
> time)

My solution approach :-
Distance travelled by the first train in $10$ minutes will be 8 km.
Averages speed of the first train will be $\frac{8}{\frac{10}{60}}= 48kmph$

Distance travelled by the second train in $13$ minutes will be $12$km.
Average speed of the second train will be $\frac{12}{\frac{13}{60}}= \frac{720}{13}kmph$

Relative speed will be $ \frac{720}{13} - 48 = \frac{96}{13}kmph$
Distance between them after $10$ minutes is $8 km$.
Time taken to overcome the first train by the second train $=\frac{8}{\frac{96}{13}}=\frac{13}{12}hours$

Distance travelled by the second train = $\frac{720}{13}kmph \times \frac{13}{12}hours=60km$ but this is wrong. What am I doing wrong? Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: They go at the same speed between stations, so the 10 minute head start of the first train will be reduced to zero after it has done 10 stations more than the second train.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the train can overtake only at a station and not in between while running as the trains have the same speed. Jaap Scherphuis's comment summarizes it. Here is a more detailed explanation -

Train $A$ has $19$ stops with $20$ sections of running with each section being $3$ km and train $B$ has $4$ stops with $5$ sections of running with each section as $12$ km. As stations are uniformly distributed, fourth stop of train $A$ is same station as first stop of train $B$ - we write it as $(4, 1)$ and stops coincide again at $(8, 2), (12, 3)$ and $(16, 4)$.

So as they are leaving their third common station ($12, 3$), train $B$ would have caught up by $3$ minutes and is now only $1$ minute behind.

As train $A$ leaves $13^{\text{th}}$ stop after one minute of stop, train $B$ has caught up with it. That is after distance of $3 \times 13 = 39$ km.

Comment: The correct answer is $18km.$

Comment: @Ganit At $39$ km train B catches up with A. So they run in parallel till next station for A. That would be $42$ km. I am counting from the starting station. As the question seeks from end station, we will have to subtract from $60$